# Replacement of sonar-core.jar

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

I was using IssueUpdater API from Sonar-core.jar during 4.5 and 5.1 versions. However I found that the latest repository for 5.3 doesn't contain sonar-core.jar pom for maven. 
Is there any alternate api for IssueUpdater or kindly help with sonar-core.jar pom for 5.3

Comment: `sonar-core` is no more deployed into Maven central since SonarQube 5.2. Please read [topic on SonarQube mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/xSu0JIAVLIM).

Comment: is there any work around for sonar-core for 5.3. Seems its expected for 5.4 per the mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sonar-core is no more deployed into Maven central since SonarQube 5.2